# DataGridColumn binding in Code

Tags: binding, wpftoolkit, datagridcolumn

I am searching a simple method through which i can bind my DataGridColumn with a Datatable columns on the fly. I should also be able to define the width of each column.

Example :-

If My program generates 5 columns  in a datatable, so the DataGrid should be able to dispaly 5 columns with each having different column width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

```
dtgrdAtlas.Columns.Add(
                        new DataGridTextColumn
                        {
                            Header = dc.ColumnName,
                            Width = 100,
                            IsReadOnly = true,
                            Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", dc.ColumnName))
                        });

dtgrdAtlas = DataGrid
```

dc = DataColumn belonging to a data table

It does the binding too!